# ExtJS4 simple textfield and label position

Tags: extjs, label, textfield, justify

I have simple textfield but with larger height then normal:

[image]

definition is:

```
{
    xtype:      'textfield',
    itemId:     'POL_OGIN',
    fieldLabel: 'Login:',
    allowBlank: false,
    height:     60,
    name:       login',
 },
```

and I have no idea how to position label text "Login:", just center it vertically. Could you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer below fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2941&view/editor

As there was no cls/any other config readily available to change fieldLabel,so i added afterrender listener for field & changed fieldLabel's top.Also there is other approach as add cls to fieldLabel and assign margin-top there.Below is code:

```
listeners: {
            afterrender: function (field) {
                var height=field.getHeight()/2-10;//10 for label height
                field.labelCell.dom.querySelector('label').style['margin-top'] = height.toString()+'px';

                //-----OR----
                //Added class below
                //field.labelEl.addCls('loginTextFieldCls');
                //In cls give margin-top
            }
        }
```

Check if it helps you or not.

Comment: Yes, THANK YOU, listener is working as I need, so one more answer in this case please, I have a few fields where I need such a operation (some cards with different forms) so could I define such a operation globaly for my application (e.g. define my own xtype: X'textfield')?

Comment: Yes you can use same thing for other components BUT ONLY places where field label is used.Can you mark My answer as right answer with tick so that other users may refer to this directly.

Comment: Foregive me if I'm wrong but I'm looking for answer in different question but close to ExtJS. Would you be so kind as to look at it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849194/extjs4-display-pdf

Comment: Are you asking me to answer your mentioned question ? Can you please create its fiddle for that question.

Comment: In teh mean time I solved this problem. Thanks anyway!